# Spring JPA not connecting with MySql Workbench database

Tags: spring, jpa, mysql-workbench

My Spring JPA is not connecting with MySql Workbench database

[![Model Class][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCt63.png

[![Repo Interface][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo0ge.png

[![Application prop][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P8Cr.png

[![Controller][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgi6s.png

[![Main Class][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqCxh.png

Comment: error log please